# 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

```
select `Nom`,`Prenom` from 
`pi_photographes`
where
`IdPhotographe`=(select 
`IdPhotographe`
from`pi_photos`
where`Description`="Site de Palmyre");
```

base
Photos [ IdPhoto, FichPhoto, Dimension, Description, IdPhotographe#, RefBien# ]

Photographes [ IdPhotographe, Nom, Prenom ]

Comment: This is not a clear question, nor does it show any research effort.

Comment: The error means that if you execute the statement `select IdPhotographe from pi_photos where Description ="Site de Palmyre"`it returns more than one row. Either your data is wrong and you should fix that and add proper checks or your statement is wrong and you should add `distinct` to the mix.

Comment: It means that there are more than one record in your pi_photos where description is "Site de Palmyre".

Comment: there are two record in pi_photos where description is "Site de Palmyre" How can I do？

Comment: The quick fix to make the query output something would be to add `distinct` after the select in the subselect but there's no way for us to know if that returns *meaningfull* data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IdPhotographe IN(subquery ...)` for multiples and for  one, you need to restrict your sub query to give one record by putting limit in subquery,while using = operator you must restrict your subquery to give one result

For one record

```
select `Nom`,`Prenom` from 
`pi_photographes`
where
`IdPhotographe`=(select 
`IdPhotographe`
from`pi_photos`
where`Description`="Site de Palmyre" LIMIT 1);
```

For multiple records use `IN()`

```
select `Nom`,`Prenom` from 
`pi_photographes`
where
`IdPhotographe` IN (select 
`IdPhotographe`
from`pi_photos`
where`Description`="Site de Palmyre");
```